# How to get a list of blobs in a sub container in Azure

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I need to get all the files from a storage with url: "https://example.blob.core.windows.net/file/subfile1/subfile2"
I only need to read data files( only .txt for example, so if I have .jpg or something else I should skip those) and only from subfile2, not the whole storage.

With c# btw

Comment: Hi @Wolfie, If the below answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in my system able to download the all **txt** files in container subfolder(**test is container and test1 is folder in container**) ,Try with this code .

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace listtxtblobs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Connection string");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test//container name");

            List<string> blobnames = new List<string>();
           
            var allblobs = container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);
            foreach (var b in allblobs)
            {
                
                string name = ((CloudBlockBlob)b).Name;
                Console.WriteLine(name);
                string[] names = name.Split('/');
                blobnames.Add(names[names.Length - 1]);




            }
            foreach(string name in blobnames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
                if (name.Contains(".txt"))
                {
                    string filePath = "local file path\\" + name;
                    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test1\\"+ name);
                    blockBlob.DownloadToFile(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Folder structure in azure storage**

[image]

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Downloaded the all txt files in local folder

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping out